# Printing multiple variables in tcl

Tags: tcl, puts

I have to print multiple variables in a single `puts` like this

```
puts "$n1_$n2_$n3_$n4"
```

where `n1` , `n2` , `n3` , `n4` are 4 variables.

It wont print and will show error `n1_ : no such variable`

Expected output should be something like this (example)

```
01_abc_21_akdd
```

Comment: Got it: i tried putting \ before every `_` and worked. Like this: `puts "$n1\_$n2\_$n3\_$n4`

Answer (score 1):

Variable names in Tcl can be any string in Tcl, there are no restrictions but if you want to use special characters (those not in the range of `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`, and letters in different languages depending on the platform and locale), you have to either brace the expression names or use other workarounds (like with the answer of Hoodiecrow).

What this means is that if you have a variable named `abc.d`, and if you use `$abc.d`, the Tcl engine will try to find the variable `$abc` because `.` is not a 'normal' character.

But if you have a variable named `abc` and use `$abcd`, or `$abc_d`, then the engine will start looking for the variables `abcd` or `abc_d` and *not* `abc`.

Because of this, you will have to use braces between the variable name for example:

```
${n1}
```

The reason why putting a backslash works is that `\` is not a 'normal' character and after reading the above, it should be a little more obvious how things worked.

---

There are a few things that yet can go in variable names which don't need bracing and still mean something, except that something is 'special':

1. `::`: This is usually used for scoping purposes. For instance if you have a global variable named `my_var`, you can also use `$::my_var` to refer to it. Here `::` tells Tcl that `my_var` is a global variable. Note that if there are more than two `:` in a row they will not add up:

   ```
   % set ::y 5
   5
   % set ::::y
   5
   % set :::y
   5
   ```

   `::` is usually used to define the namespace the variable is in. For example, `$mine::var` is a variable called `var` in the namespace with a name of `mine`.
2. `()`: These are used for arrays. `$arr(key)` is a variable with two parts: the array name `arr` and the key name `key`. Note: you can have an array named  and a key named  because...

   ```
   % set () abc
   abc
   % puts $()
   abc
   % array get ""
   {} abc
   ```

There might be some more, but those are the basics you could look out for.

Answer (score 0):

Two other ways:

```
puts "${n1}_${n2}_${n3}_${n4}"

puts [format "%s_%s_%s_%s" $n1 $n2 $n3 $n4]
```

Documentation: [format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm)

(Note: the 'Hoodiecrow' mentioned in Jerry's answer is me, I used that nick earlier.)